# Increasing point size in h2o.shap_summary_plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, h2o, shap

I would like to increase point in h2o SHAP summary plot. I tried to modify object that is returned by h2o.shap_summary_plot:

```
plt=h2o.shap_summary_plot(model, test)
plt=plt+geom_point(size = 4)
```

Unfortunately old points remain in the background, and position of the new/large points is changed - these are plotted on straight lines:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to modify this plot is to take the `data` from it and recreate the plot:

```
ggplot(plt$data, aes(.data$feature, .data$contribution, color = .data$normalized_value, text = .data$row)) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
        geom_point(position = h2o:::position_jitter_density(), alpha = 0.5, size = 4) +
        scale_color_gradient(low = "#00AAEE", high = "#FF1166") +
        coord_flip() +
        labs(y = "SHAP Contribution", x = "Feature") +
        theme_bw()
```

Comment: Yes, I realised that it is ggplot output and you have to modify relevant layer point size: `plt$layers[[2]]$aes_params$size=4`